# What the best program for string manipulation

Tags: string, string-manipulation, text-manipulation

I would like to know the best program (Surely a text editor) to make string manipulation like string substituion.

By the way, I would like to do the next:
[String manipulation of type String substitution in mathematical expression](https://superuser.com/questions/213865/string-manipulation-of-type-string-substitution-in-mathematical-expression)

Thank you so much!

Comment: On what platform?

Comment: To do the type of manipulation you asked about in your previous question, Perl or Python are your best bets (my answer there uses Perl). AWK *might* be able to do it. It would take a really complex `sed` script to even come close. It may be that the regex processing in vim or emacs is up to the challenge. @GreenMatt: The One True Platform - Windows. ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My preferences are in this order: perl, vim (vi, gvim, etc.) substitution commands, sed, and awk.

perl is a heavy software program that can do math as well.  See http://perlmonks.org/ for more details.

Vi is the well known text editor all *ix systems have (Linux, Unix, etc.), which, incidentally, can do some nice scripting.

Sed is, well see http://linux.die.net/man/1/sed

Awk (gawk and its brethren) is, well see http://linux.die.net/man/1/awk

... almost forgot. The absolute best, and with a price tag to match, is PowerGrep.  Without a doubt, the easiest way to formulate complex queries and replacements of text in DOC, TXT, and other files.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/39384/best-grep-like-tool if you are interested in regular expressions and Grep

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [sed](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html)